Find cookie name from beginning
I need to find cookie name and i try to use
import Cookies from "js-cookie"
const regexp = /^commercelayer_order-id/;
const orderId = Cookies.get(regexp)

i am stuck
I ve tried several ways to find by name , now i try a regexp.

Where did you get the idea that the argument to Cookies.get() can be a regexp? I don't see that in the documentation.

So , how can i find the cookie that start with commercelayer_order-id

There doesn't seem to be anything built into that library that performs a partial match of cookie names. You can get all the cookies and do the match yourself.
let orderId;
for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(Cookies.get()) {
  if (name.startsWith('commercelayer_order-id')) {
    orderId = value;
    break;
  }
}

